# code for a simple fighting game but after a player health becomes 0 game continues its loop

Tags: c++

so this is the entire code, it has a display function which does the displaying and processing of inputs and a main function which passes the display when the GameOver function is set to false

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define key_x 88
using namespace std;
bool GameOver = false;


void Display() {
    int choose;
    char ch;
    system("color 04");
    cout << "WELCOME" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        cout << "Character " << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "choose character number: ";
    cin >> choose;


    if (choose > 4) {
        cout << "Enter valid character number: ";
        cin >> choose;

    }
    cout << "Selected Character is " << choose << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    int random = (rand() % 4) + 1;
    system("color 02");
    cout << "ENEMY IS CHARACTER " << random << endl; 

     int hp1 = 100;
     int hp2 = 100;

    cout << "Character " << choose << "(" << hp1 << ")" << " VS. Character " << random << "(" << hp2 << ")" << endl;


    while(!GameOver)                      
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int rand1 = (rand() % 100) + 1;
        int rand2 = (rand() % 100) + 1;

        int NewHp1 = hp1 - rand1;
        int NewHp2 = hp2 - rand2;
        

            cout << "Press any key to attack" << endl;

            ch = (_getch());
            int value = ch;
            while (value == key_x)
                break;

            cout << "Enemy has " << NewHp2 << " health left." << endl;

            system("pause");

            cout << "You have " << NewHp1 << " health left." << endl;

            if (NewHp2 <= 0) {
                cout << "YOU WIN!!" << endl;
                break;
                GameOver = true;
            }

            else if (NewHp1 <= 0) {
                system("color 04");
                cout << "YOU LOSE" << endl;
                break;
                GameOver = true;
            }

            else
            {
            
                continue;

            }
    }

}


int main() {
    while(!GameOver)
          Display();
    
}
```

after the hp goes below 0 the game just seems to continue taking the hp as 100 and restart, could anyone help me resolve this issue.
I know this code is slightly messy, I have just started learning cpp

Comment: You should generally only call `srand(time(0));` once at the beginning of your program. You're setting `GameOver = true;` after the `break;` so that code is never executed. The else with continue is not necessary.

Comment: that is correct but i want to generate a new number between 1 - 100 everytime it iterates through the loop hence its inside the loop

Comment: There's no guarantee that it will be a new number each time and if you seed it twice with the same value you're guaranteed the same number. Better off seeding it once and letting the sequence play out. If you need unique numbers then you should add logic for that rather than rely on hope.

Answer (score 1):

```
            break;
            GameOver = true;
```

When the `break` is encountered, it breaks, so `GameOver = true;` doesn't run. Remove the `break`.

```
        else
        {  
            continue;
        }
```

is superfluous. There's nothing left to run in this loop, so it will continue anyway. Remove this `else` block too.

And lastly, you forgot to update `hp1` and `hp2` with `NewHp1` and `NewHp2`:

```
hp1 = NewHp1;
hp2 = NewHp2;
```

just before the end of the loop.